# Can a good photographic objective be much thinner than wide?

Tags: optics, lenses

Modern photographic objectives are made of multiple lenses with constant refractive index in each. The result is that thickness of an objective is comparable to (and sometimes even larger than) its diameter.

Suppose we can make an arbitrary object with any distribution of refractive index we want (up to discreteness of molecular structure). Let's also limit ourselves to shapes where maximal thickness of the resulting lens would be, say, 100 times smaller than its diameter.

If we were to create such a lens, would there be any physical (optical) reasons to be unable to minimize all the aberrations that modern objectives minimize, to the same level of quality? Maybe some conservation laws that would require larger thickness, or something else...

Comment: In the other extreme, a pinhole is an OK 'objective'. At some point you get into major mechanical issues (including build-in stresses), so one would have to consider a broader range of aberrations than normal.

Comment: "pancake" objectives are like 1/4 of their diameter. And we can make almost arbitrary spatial refractive index, they are called GRIN lenses. But I don't think you will see them very soon (say 5/10 years) in commercial objectives. I might be wrong but I think that a single lens for full visible radiation would probably work well chromatically corrected only for a small distance range to an object (say like 30m). But not like full focus range (I might be wrong).

Comment: @JoséAndrade if you look closer at a pancake objective, you'll see that the front lens itself is about 1/3 of the diameter of the assembly: the large diameter is simply to accommodate the large mount. E.g. [Canon 24mm f/2.8](https://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/images/24mm-f28-stm/diagram.gif). And then the lens system is still roughly as thick as it is wide, so that's nothing different from normal objectives. As for GRIN: can a single flat GRIN lens really completely replace an objective? I thought they are functionally more like single aspherical lenses, not like objectives.

Comment: In that you are right, but the size is so that the objective is functional for human hands and fitting the bayonet, but you are right its more like 1x1. Coming back to the question, a GRIN flat lens, yes, but you asked about free-form lens+ GRIN, which I think would be possible but with the constraints I said. Not so long ago a paper came out, a Mexican physicist, who derived an analytic formula for the back shape of a lens to guarantee no aberrations, if you have the shape of the front and refractive index of lens. But again, lens assemblies are made so you can change imaging distances

Comment: @JoséAndrade do you mean [this paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2014.0608)? It only talks about _spherical_ aberrations. And then, the lenses discussed there are far from being thin.

Comment: I am not sure. I had an idea the paper was from 2019. Yes, they are not thin, but are made from single refractive index...it would be in the realm of possibility to think about adding both that and GRIN. But again, the biggest problem is making a system which would be corrected for many imaging planes, at different distances

Comment: I wish there were an Optics SE. I think that this site is too large, and so good, thoughtful questions get overlooked. [Splitting it up](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12734/83380) perhaps by specialty would be one solution.